# How can I use wcf service in grpc in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: wcf, grpc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have WCF service with .NET Framework and I have a gRPC with ASP.NET Core 6.

I got this error when I call the WCF service in my grpc service:

> unexpected HTTP status code received from server: 500 (Internal Server Error); transport: received unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"

My grpc:

```
public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    long[] recId = null;
    byte[] status = null;
    
    var service = new SendService();
    var response = service.SendSMS("user", "pass", "SimCard",
                    new[] { "09123546789" }, "تستی است",
                    false, ref recId, ref status);
    
    return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
                {
                    //Message = "Hello " + request.Name
                    Message = "response is  " + response 
                });
}
```